# Exception при работе с базой данных MySql из android app

Tags: php, android, mysql, исключения

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText firstname, lastname, age;
Button insert, show;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
String insertUrl = "http://127.0.0.1/students/insertStudent.php";
String showUrl = "http://127.0.0.1/students/showStudents.php";
TextView result;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    firstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    lastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    insert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insert);
    show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showstudents);
    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            System.out.println("ww");
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    showUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                    try {
                        JSONArray students = response.getJSONArray("students");
                        for (int i = 0; i < students.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject student = students.getJSONObject(i);

                            String firstname = student.getString("firstname");
                            String lastname = student.getString("lastname");
                            String age = student.getString("age");

                            result.append(firstname + " " + lastname + " " + age + " \n");
                        }
                        result.append("===\n");

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    System.out.append(error.getMessage());

                }
            });
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        }
    });

    insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }) {

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> parameters  = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    parameters.put("firstname",firstname.getText().toString());
                    parameters.put("lastname",lastname.getText().toString());
                    parameters.put("age",age.getText().toString());

                    return parameters;
                }
            };
            requestQueue.add(request);
        }

    });


}

}
```

при нажатии на кнопу "insert student" вываливается

```
03-15 09:43:10.813 19189-19243/practise.mysql_php_json I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 42 with tag 59c3b57d00000000(1505998205) for uid -1 failed errno=-2
03-15 09:43:10.863 19189-19243/practise.mysql_php_json I/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: tagSocketFd(42, 1505998205, -1) failed with errno-2
03-15 09:43:10.872 19189-19243/practise.mysql_php_json I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 42 failed errno=-2
03-15 09:43:10.872 19189-19243/practise.mysql_php_json W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: untagSocket(42) failed with errno -2
```

при нажатии на "showstudent" вываливается

```
03-15 09:44:18.243 19189-19189/practise.mysql_php_json I/System.out: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 80) after 2500ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)ww
03-15 09:44:18.263 19189-19244/practise.mysql_php_json I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 42 with tag 59c3b57d00000000(1505998205) for uid -1 failed errno=-2
03-15 09:44:18.263 19189-19244/practise.mysql_php_json I/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: tagSocketFd(42, 1505998205, -1) failed with errno-2
03-15 09:44:18.263 19189-19244/practise.mysql_php_json I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 42 failed errno=-2
03-15 09:44:18.263 19189-19244/practise.mysql_php_json W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: untagSocket(42) failed with errno -2
```

Comment: `IP` 127.0.0.1 значит, что вы хотите приконнектиться к самому устройству, с которого коннектитесь. *К самому себе*. Если коннектитесь с телефона - 127.0.0.1 - это будет IP адресс самого телефона. Если с компьютера - адресс самого компьютера.     А теперь подумайте, запущен ли на самом телефоне веб-сервер, накотором есть  файл `students/insertStudent.php`?

Answer (score 1):

> IP 127.0.0.1 значит, что вы хотите приконнектиться к самому устройству, с которого коннектитесь. К самому себе. Если коннектитесь с телефона - 127.0.0.1 - это будет IP адресс самого телефона. Если с компьютера - адресс самого компьютера. А теперь подумайте, запущен ли на самом телефоне веб-сервер, накотором есть файл students/insertStudent.php?

Разобрался.... использую wamp... заменил в настройках апачи порт на 8080, теперь адрес 10.0.2.2:8080/students/insertStudent.php